# Return a default date with TryParseExact in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, tryparse

Why does this function not return the default value?

If parsing fails a date of **1900-01-01** should be returned.

It instead returns **01/01/0001** which is the date defualt for .NET

```
Public Shared Function ParseDate(FieldName As Object) As Date
  Dim ID As Date = "1900-01-01"

  If TypeOf FieldName Is TextBox Then
    If Date.TryParseExact(FieldName.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, ID) Then
      ID = FieldName.Text
    End If
  End If

  Return ID
End Function
```

Comment: You can write `Date = "1900-01-01"` in else block of `If Date.TryParseExact`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks this was my next option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood how `DateTime.TryParse` works. It doesn't return your passed `DateTime` as fallback value. An out parameter is not interested in your input argument. `TryParse` will assign the   default value of `DateTime` which is `MinValue` to the out-parameter if it could not be parsed. That's [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx).

> When this method returns, contains the `DateTime` value equivalent to
>   the date and time contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, **or
>   [`MinValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) if the conversion failed**. The conversion fails if the s
>   parameter is `null`, is an empty string (""), or does not contain a
>   valid string representation of a date and time. This parameter is
>   passed uninitialized.

So you see it returns [`DateTime.MinValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) if it could not parse successully.

---

But you should use the returned `Boolean` anyway to determine if it could be parsed:

```
Dim validDate = Date.TryParseExact(FieldName.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, ID)
```

---

The above function can be rewritten to:

```
Public Shared Function ParseDate(FieldName As Object) As Date
    If TypeOf FieldName Is TextBox Then
        Dim dt as Date
        If Date.TryParseExact(FieldName.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then
            Return dt
        End If
    End If

    Return New Date(1900, 1, 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, this is enlightening. I always assumed (incorrectly) that the value wouldn't be updated if conversion failed. Simply updating this in the else statement is the way to go I think.

Comment: @Obsidian: please set `Option Strict` to `On` and don't treat a `DateTime` like a string. That would never compile and that's good. Edited my answer to show the complete method which would also compile with option-strict (or C#).